# Are variables always assumed to be real in Jordan Decomposition?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, symbolic

If you give the following input in *Mathematica* 9.0 (Student Edition):

```
JordanDecomposition /@ ({{1, #}, {#, -1}} & /@ {i, I})
```

*Mathematica* gives you two completely different results. Shouldn't there be several cases for the decomposition in case that the eigenvalues are undefined or coincide?

Comment: Symbolic linear algebra in Mathematica assumes generic values for symbols. No error here (other than in the flagging of the question).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau yeah but there is no tag like "mathematica behaves different to what i expect" :)

Comment: An "Unexpected result" tag could indeed be useful. Though I expect it might get used to the point of not retaining much meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To settle this once and for all:

Consider the Jordan decomposition of a symbolic generalization of your matrix:

```
jd[x_, y_] = JordanDecomposition[{{1, x + I y}, {x + I y, -1}}]
```

whose explicit expression is

```
   {{{(1 - Sqrt[1 + x^2 + 2 I x y - y^2])/(x + I y),
      (1 + Sqrt[1 + x^2 + 2 I x y - y^2])/(x + I y)}, {1, 1}}, 
    {{-Sqrt[1 + x^2 + 2 I x y - y^2], 0}, {0, Sqrt[1 + x^2 + 2 I x y - y^2]}}}
```

Of note in this result is that the second element is a diagonal matrix, thus showing that `JordanDecomposition[]` tacitly assumes diagonalizability. We also note that one of the eigenvalues is the negative of the other; we can thus expect failure if these eigenvalues both become equal; that is:

```
Reduce[1 + x^2 + 2 I x y - y^2 == 0 && x ∈ Reals && y ∈ Reals]
   (y == -1 && x == 0) || (y == 1 && x == 0)
```

Or put another way,

```
x + I y /. {ToRules[%]}
   {-I, I}
```

These are our problem points. Check:

```
jd[0, -1]
   {{{I, I}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}}

jd[0, 1]
   {{{-I, -I}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}}
```

and we see that the results here are not what they should be:

```
JordanDecomposition[{{1, -I}, {-I, -1}}]
   {{{I, I}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}}

JordanDecomposition[{{1, -I}, {-I, -1}}]
   {{{-I, -I}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}}
```

Ah, there's that Jordan block!

---

In summary, per Daniel's comment:

> Symbolic linear algebra in *Mathematica* assumes generic values for symbols.

In other words: `JordanDecomposition[]` won't assume your matrix is defective unless it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

From the tutorial on Advanced Matrix Operations,

"Jordan decomposition in general writes any square matrix in the form as s.j.s^-1."

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedMatrixOperations.html

It does not state that the form is unique.

```
m1 = {{1, i}, {i, -1}};

{s1, j1} = JordanDecomposition[m1]
```

> {{{(1 - Sqrt[1 + i^2])/i, 
>          (1 + Sqrt[1 + i^2])/i}, 
>        {1, 1}}, {{-Sqrt[1 + i^2], 0}, 
>        {0, Sqrt[1 + i^2]}}}

```
m1 == s1.j1.Inverse[s1] // Simplify
```

> True

```
m2 = m1 /. i -> I;

{s2, j2} = JordanDecomposition[m2]
```

> {{{-I, -I}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}}

```
m2 == s2.j2.Inverse[s2]
```

> True

Consequently, both are valid Jordan decompositions and neither assumes or requires that matrix values be real.

Comment: But the form is unique up to Permutation of the blocks, here one time we have a diagonal Matrix and one time, we don't have, that is impossible