# How to correctly calculate symbolic eigenvectors

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, symbolic

I give a minimalistic example of my problem:

I have a matrix:

```
m[a_,b_]:={{0,-a+b},{b,0}};
```

I define the eigenvectors as:

```
e[a_,b_]:=Eigenvectors[m[a,b],Cubics\[Rule]True,Quartics\[Rule]True]
```

and get the result

```
e[a_,b_]= {{-(Sqrt[b (-a + b)]/b), 1}, {Sqrt[b (-a + b)]/b, 1}}
```

If I calculate `e[a,0]` I get

```
e[a,0]={{1, 0}, {0, 0}}
```

but if I store the symbolic equation for the eigenvectors, speaking

```
f[a_,b_]={{-(Sqrt[b (-a + b)]/b), 1}, {Sqrt[b (-a + b)]/b, 1}}
```

and try to calculate `f[a,0]` I get the "intermediate" result cause the algorithm tries to divide by 0.

How can I get the symbolic output of eigenvectors to give the correct result?

Comment: Your matrix becomes similar to a Jordan block for $b=0$. `Eigenvectors[]` does not automatically assume a symbolic matrix is defective.

Comment: How can i add this exeption to get an global solution?

Comment: A strategy similar to the one done [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87501) would work.

Comment: I read the comment but i dont understand how this solves my problem.

Comment: I have an symbolic expression for the eigenvectors and want to get the right result replacing the variables a and b by the values for every case of a and b

Comment: My point is that you won't always get a full set of eigenvectors if your matrix is defective.

Comment: If i calculate explicitelyEigenvectors[m[a,0]] i get the right eigenvectors {{1, 0}, {0, 0}}. I want to understand how mathematica does this in that cause but with the general output {{-(Sqrt[b (-a + b)]/b), 1}, {Sqrt[b (-a + b)]/b, 1}} this is not reproducable

Comment: My question is cause i have a large matrix where the calculation of the eigenvectors takes several hours and i want a closed analytical result for the vectors and not calculate the whole system again for each value i set

Comment: "If i calculate explicitelyEigenvectors[m[a,0]] i get the right eigenvectors {{1, 0}, {0, 0}}" - what *Mathematica* is saying in that case is that in only found **one** eigenvector, and just padded the list with zeros so that you get something square. If you can't or won't use `JordanDecomposition[]` on your matrix, you don't know when your matrix will be defective or not.

Comment: How relate the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of my matrix with the  s and j values of the JordanDecomposition[]? I have a hermitian matrix  and only want the right result for the eigenvectors if i set the parameter to 0

Comment: "I have a hermitian matrix" - tss... your example wasn't Hermitian. In any case, try orthogonalizing your eigenvector set.

Answer (score 0):

e[a,0]={{1,0},{0,0}}.But actually {1,0} is not a correct eigenvector to {{0,-a},{0,0}}.(you can try yourself to see). so the symbolic output of e[a_,b_] is not correct when you set b=0. It can not be used to your purpose either.

Comment: Huh? That eigenvector corresponds to an eigenvalue of $0$. What you might have meant is that an arbitrary vector could have been assigned as the eigenvector corresponding to the zero eigenvalue.

Comment: I see. you are right. maybe the eigenvector function doesn't use the symbolic expression to deal with numerical input. if your purpose is to get a symbolic expression for convenience in later use, may be you can first get a symbolic expression, then find its singular points. use the expression while its not singular and use eigenvector function only for those singular points

Comment: ok dr.bian, that's what i already feared. There is probably no way to get the eigenvectors of singular points using the symbolic expression of my eigenvectors. In that case it seems to be more easy to me to "not" use the symbolic expression.